# Entity Framework - Relationships between two classes without navigation properties using Fluent

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes (Person and Phone) and I didn't figure out how to create a relationship between these classes without create a navigation property.
Is there some way to do that? Or I HAVE to create a navigation property?

Writing in T-SQL, I'm looking for somethink like that:

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PHONE] WITH NOCHECK
>         ADD CONSTRAINT [RelationName1] FOREIGN KEY
>             ( [PERSONID] )
>             REFERENCES [dbo].[PERSON]
>             ( [PERSONID] )

In example below, I don't know how to write this sentence:
`modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany<Phone>()....` ?????:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany<Phone>()...?????
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: No it is not possible and I don't know why you even want it. Wat's the point of a relationship, if you don't want to use it in the code altogether?

Comment: @ManishMishra: For 2 reasons: 1 - I have problems to serialize those classes using WebApi/JSON (but in this case, if I just create one-side navigation property, it is not a problem). And 2 - I want to avoid EF to insert child informations in SaveChanges. If I create a List<Phone> in Person class, and MyContext.People.Add(person), I don't want to EF insert (or update) any phone in database. //// So, I'm looking for to have relationships in my database (created by EF), but using my POCO classes without it.

Answer (score 1):

You do, I think, need a navigation property in at least one direction.  If this is causing serialization problems, have you investigated adding attributes to prevent it from being serialized?  For example, add the `DataContractAttribute` on your classes, and add `DataMemberAttribute` to all the properties that you *do* want to serialize.

This would give you the following (in which I use attributes, but you could use fluent config instead):

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Phone
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int PhoneId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    // No [DataMember] here.
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // If I had a Phones collection on Person, I could use the other override
        // of WithMany.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>().HasRequired(q => q.Person).WithMany();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olly, thank you. Just one comment: One person could have no phone, one phone or more than one phone. Sorry about my English, but it is a 1->0..N relation. So, PhoneId is KEY for Phone table, and PersonId is the foreign key. And thankyou for teach me about [DataContract] and [DataMember] annotations!

Comment: Sorry!  I didn't look carefully enough at your model.  I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

one way (the only in fact, referring to first comment of your question) I imagine to reach the goal is by overriding the initializer and sending sql command from the seed method of the initializer. Something like:

```
public class CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsWithSeedData : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SomeContext> {

    protected override void Seed(SomeContext context) {
        base.Seed(context);

        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PHONE] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [RelationName1] FOREIGN KEY ( [PERSONID] ) REFERENCES [dbo].[PERSON] ( [PERSONID] )");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I thought that it would be simple to do, just point one INT property to other INT property. I'm considering to use LIST<Phone> in Person class... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, following I can suggest

**Problems to Serialize those classes using WebApi/JSON** :

well, it is a serious problem when you try to serialize any entity having many-to-many (circular) relationship. Even Ignore Circular Reference (as provided by JSON.NET Serializer) doesn't work. The best that you can do is to, instead of serializing your exact entity, you can serialize a `Linq .Select`  list of this entity i.e. Select only scalar properties or ignore circular and not required navigational properties from the Select list and then serialize it.

**I want to avoid EF to insert child informations in SaveChanges**

What you mean? If you have a foreign key in your table, you got to have a master table with a primary key, to which this foreign key(PersonId) refers to right? That means, you have to have a table PersonMaster or similar with or without data. Entity framework does it simple for you. If you meant, you don't want to insert new data in your PersonMaster, then simply don't add a new Person object to your Phone entity, find the Person (from the same context ) and then add it. EntityFramework will simply use the primary key.
If you tried to say, you want to have a value in your personId column, which doesn't exist anywhere else and still be the foreign key, that's not possible you know that right? Plain SQL.

Comment: Manish, My point is have just one project with my POCO classes and try to use it in my entire project (Service, Business and Data Layer). For user interface, I will create my MODELs to implement NotityPropertyChange, etc. But for my other layers, I really like to use just one "project" of poco classes!

Comment: About second topic, in interface layer, I will prepare a new "Phone" that have one owner (person). But person already exists in database. and I would like to EF just insert a new phone. If personId does not exist in database, an error will be returned from SQL Server, for example. I think it is simple to resolve, just setting some EF properties, or something like that.